How to debug a complete freeze in Neovim?
Seems pretty basic, but don't know what to do.
When I load a big file, Vim freezes. I can't do anything:
I did the following:

Added function to disable LSP clients on big files.
Disable all events
Run profile (but I can't stop profile so nothing is written) .

After all of that still freezing.
Is there a profiling command which can be used in case of a hang that is not recoverable( i.e. can't run :profile stop )
This seems to be the problematic stack:


Next step is to use frida.

Found the issue (github copilot). But I don't know about it generally.

I would always try vim --clean and variants to determine whether the issues lies with the editor or a plugin script. That is, start with the advice in https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

@eyalkarni, you said you solved the problem. Do you have any advice to share?

The only reason I was able to solve it is that it wasn't complete as I initially thought . I regained control and using profile was able to detect it.

Large files maybe cumbersome for Vim.
From my own experience with recent version of Vim the problems are usually in:

Folding
Syntax (syntax coloring)
Some plugin (e.g. csv although csv is dealing with very large file above 20 Mb very nicely)

To reduce the performance problem related to syntax you can add the following setting that helps with buffers that contains very long lines.
set synmaxcol=300

I'm using vim-anyfold plugin for creating the folds. I have the following setting to activate it for json buffers only if their size is below 0.1 MB.
autocmd Filetype json if (getfsize(expand("<afile>")) < 0.1 * 1024 * 1024) | execute "AnyFoldActivate" | endif

Other Authors (vim-tips#343, Ali Haidar) point additionally:

Wrapping long lines
Highlighting search ('hlsearch')
Backup ('backup', ``'writebackup'`)
Word completion ('complete')
Undo ('undolevels')
Swap files (swapfile)

Not exactly an answer to your question but you could be interested to the following plugin that makes its best to deal with large files:

LargeFile (if you like LargeFile you could be interested to my personal branch where I have fixed two bugs LargeFile)


Really improves performance it seems. Thanks!

@eyalkarni Thanks for the feedback! Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :--)

I would like too. But there is something open. The original question hasn't been answered. It seems that there is no way to debug it if the hang is a complete hang (non-recoverable). Which happened to me too.

I understand. I see no solution :-| Maybe someone else has a idea. Not all questions can rest ;-)

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/30647
